# iPhone Compatibility check

Tags: css, browser

We have written media query for iPhone resolution for our site. Now, we want to check it in real iPhone devices but we don't have an iPhone. However, we have Mac Laptop, is it possible to imitate iPhone through Mac laptop?

Please guide me!

Answer (score 0):

If you have google chrome installed in your MAC laptop, you can open inspect element using f12 key, or right click anywhere on page and click inspect element.

Then find attached screenshot with 2 red marked circles.
YOu can click on mobile view and select iphone as device.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Will I have a different response in mobile view while checking it on Windows OS and MAC OS?

Comment: It shouldnt be. As this is designed to be able to check for specific device view, the output should be the same regardless of any OS.

Comment: I understand. However, I have noticed that I can see the design of our site is ok while checking the site at Mobile view(iPhone) in the browser but the design seems to be collapsed in real mobile devices. I have done the above said test in Windows OS.

Comment: Probably this is related to css as well. It is possible that some css dont get supported for safari browser. The result you are seeing is in chrome and on device you are probably seeing result in safari browser. Unfortunately i have not safari installed in my system. You can check if safari browser provides the same debugging tool or not as chrome. If yes the it may be a perfect result.

Comment: Do you have xcode and simulator installed on MAC pc ?